# How to write an error handling block using try/catch and finally?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand the result of a challenge in my course and I am stuck to pass, as the result is not matching with what they are expecting. The challenge tasks are:

1. Write a try/catch block that tries to console log myVar, which should be deliberately undefined, so as to generate an error
   Catch the error.
2. In the catch block, store the entire error in a variable, `myError`
3. In the catch block, store the error's name in a variable, `myErrorName`
4. In the catch block, store the error's message in a variable, `myErrorMessage`
   Write a finally block that checks to see if `myError` exists.
5. If so, define a variable, result, which has the following value: There was an error `(myErrorName: myErrorMessage)`
6. If not, define the same variable, result, but assign it the value "No errors occurred!'

The approach I have is as follow:

```
try{
  myVar();
}
catch(err){
  var myError = err;
  var myErrorName = err.name;
  var myErrorMessage = err.message;
}
 finally{
  if(myError == err){
    var result = "There was an error (myErrorName:myErrorMessage)";
 }else{
    console.log("No error ocurred");
 }
}
```

Comment: You have a typo: `var myErro = err;` is missing the `r` on the end of `myErro`.

Comment: *"as the result is not matching with what they are expecting"* Do they give you any more information than that?

Comment: Well, the result is never returned (as per what is shown here), so whatever system is executing this has no way to check it.

Comment: Isn't this `try{
  myVar();
}` supposed to me `try{
  console.log(myVar);
}` ???

Comment: You're misusing the finally block. It is used for clean-up, e.g. closing the database connections in Node.js world.

Comment: @SilviuBurcea this is a school assignment. It is to get people familiar with the `try-catch-finally` construct, rather than manage database connections.

Comment: @SilviuBurcea - It's a misuse of `finally`, but it's not the *OP's* misuse of `finally`. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder \*shrug\* when I was learning programming, I was taught by initially "misusing" objects and scopes. The focus was on other things and it would have been overwhelming to tell me *why* I'd want to use or avoid given constructs when I was struggling with writing code that compiles and/or doesn't throw NPEs. So I don't really think it's a "misuse" - it's not how you'd *typically* use this in production code but...most of the code written while learning I would never want in my code base at work, either. The requirements are simply different.

Comment: @VLAZ - Fair enough. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two primary problems with that code:

1. You have a typo: `var myErro = err;` is missing the `r` on the end of `myErro`.
2. You're trying to use `err` in the `finally` block, but it's only in scope in the `catch` block.

...and then a few more that don't match what it seems like the assignment is telling you to do

3. You're not doing #1, you're doing something else which coincidentally also tries to use `myVar`
4. You don't have any code implementing #6.
5. Your code assigning `result` when there's an error is putting `myErrorName` and `myErrorMessage` literally in the string, rather than using the values of those variables.
6. Your message for when no errors have occurred is not the same as the message they told you to use, it has slight differences (including a typo). Programming is at least partially about attention to detail. :-)

You don't need `if (myError == err)`, just `if (myError)` will do:

```js
try{
  myVar();
}
catch(err){
  var myError = err;
  var myErrorName = err.name;
  var myErrorMessage = err.message;
}
 finally{
  if(myError){
    var result = "There was an error (myErrorName:myErrorMessage)";
    console.log(result);
 }else{
    console.log("No error ocurred");
 }
}
```

*(I added a `console.log` so we'd see the error case.)*

**I've only addressed #1 and #2 in the above, the rest are left as an exercise for you to complete. :-)**

---

I should note that I wouldn't write it that way. Declaring a variable in the `catch` block that you use in the `finally` block does work, with `var` (because `var` is not block-scoped and is hoisted), but it's misleading to people trying to maintain the code. If you're going to use a variable in both of those blocks, move the declaration outside the blocks for clarity.

Comment: And I *think* that the message in the `if` block should actually be using the `myErrorMessage` variable

Comment: I wish there was a better way to make collaborative edits to the same post... It's super hard to edit if anybody else is as well. I better stick to comments for now. It's probably worth elaborating slightly on the fact that `myError == err` is not the right thing because it doesn't (exactly) check for existence.

Comment: @mplungjan - I was editing and don't want to solve all of the OP's problems. *List* them, but not *solve* them. I'm out of the way now. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yeah, my complaint for collaborative edits exactly. One person saves and wipes the others' progress... :(

Answer (score 0):

Check this It will work

```
try{
  console.log(myVar);
}
catch(err){
  var myError = err;
  var myErrorName = err.name;
  var myErrorMessage = err.message;
}
 finally{
  if(myError){
    var result = "There was an error ("+ myErrorName+": "+myErrorMessage+")";
 }else{
   result = "No error ocurred";
 }
}
```

Comment: Code dumps are not *useful* answers, and this doesn't address anything that the answer that already existed when you posted it didn't cover, more thoroughly, with explanations.

Comment: Read Question Properly Please @T.J.Crowder It only asked to console log myVar and declare the error in result variable

Comment: Read Comment Properly Please @ Gaurav. ;-) *(Seriously: Do you think I **didn't** read the question?)*

Comment: I used this approach